# recycled edittext inside recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

With RecyclerView, the off-screen EditTexts will be recycled. For example, if we have a list of 200 items, and it shows 2 items at one time, we will only ever have 2 EditText. They will reuse the higher EditText for the lower elements.

For example, here is a list that contains EditText showing only 2 at a time, and as the user scrolls, it will recycle and reuse them.

1. EditText A
2. Edittext B
3. EditText C (recycled)
4. EditText D (recycled)
5. ....

This means we cannot just loop over all the elements later and get the values, as they don't store their values.

So, what i am asking is that is there anyway to loop over all the items and get there values even the recycled ones and save them to firebase

EDIT:
I have a recyclerview with an edit text inside it the user enter numbers inside edit text and when he click save button a for loop iterate over all the recyclerview edit text and save data to Firebase

this is my fragment class

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.purchases_list_activity, container, false);
    mItem = new ArrayList<>();
    mAdapter = new PurchasesAdapter(getContext(), mItem, this);
    re = view.findViewById(R.id.itemsPListView);
    re.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    re.setAdapter(mAdapter);



    fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_purchases);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mItem.size(); i++) {
                final ItemsAdapter mylist = mItem.get(i);

              View childView = re.getChildAt(i);



                final EditText Qty = childView.findViewById(R.id.itemNewPcs);
                final String qty = Qty.getText().toString();

Toast.makeText(getContext(),qty+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



..
}
```

Comment: Create a List Pojo class and store values while updating Edittext.

Comment: okay can you provide me with a link that can help me create , store , and retrieve data from Pojo class thank you

Comment: also we are talking about a list anyhelp?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you might need is the `RecyclerView`'s `OnChildAttachStateChangeListener` functionality. Basically, you implement your own class that implements the [`OnChildAttachStateChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener.html) interface. Specifically, the implement the [`onChildViewAttachedToWindow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener.html#onChildViewAttachedToWindow(android.view.View)) method to do save to Firebase or add to a list that can be added to Firebase later - basically whatever you need. You just attach your custom listener via the [`addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.html#addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener)) method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: okay i will edit my question and add my code so you can check it is that okay?

Comment: Sure but just bear in mind that only you can really test your code. And also, if the code works for you, it would be appreciated if you accepted the answer. :-)

Comment: i edited my question and add the code how can implement what you said

Comment: There is a lot of other stuff for me to understand. Does it work? If there is too much needless complexity, maybe you could just change your `onChildViewAttachedToWindow()` method so that it just outputs a debug message instead of doing all of the complicated Firebase stuff. Maybe you could do that to make it easier to test.

Comment: i have edited firebase stuff by removing them can you just help me how can we exactly implement what you said and how to take the value from the recycled edittext

Comment: I don't see an instance of `RecyclerView` anywhere in the new code. What is the instance of the `RecyclerView` object that you referenced in question?

Comment: do you mean this re = view.findViewById(R.id.itemsPListView);